# Laravel route url and vuejs axious not working with unicode utf-8 issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I use my project in slug . when i use English that work fine.But when i use unicode/bangla its show in this picture .[image]
 axious not working

Comment: Show axios code

Comment: axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/blog/${this.$route.params.id}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT solved 
Axious sent request: axios.get(`en/blog/${encodeURI(this.$route.params.id)}`).then(response => {
      this.blogpostdetails = response.data.blogpostdetails;

```
});
```

And Controller:  $blogpost = Blog::with('blogcategorylist','admin','blogcomment')->whereSlug(urldecode($id))->get()->first();

Answer (score -1):

Change your request like this, it'll help

```
 let url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/blog/${this.$route.params.id};
 axios.get(encodeURI(url))
```

And in your controller just take it as usual

Comment: I've tested it with armenian letters, may be you'll need to use urldecode() in your controller, I can test it with your param if you past it here